# Steps of converting C++ opencv project on computer to opencv android

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv, android-ndk

I wrote a c++ project on my computer for stabilizing a video using `OpenCV`. But I want to write this project to android using Opencv4Android. For doing this, should I make new project or Is any way to convert that project for android by using NDK? If I can use project of mycompter, Did need many changes on that c++ codes? What steps need to convert or porting a computer opencv project to android opencv project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a really general question, so I will try to break it down a bit.

First, lets forget about the openCV for a second.

You want to create a c++ project for Android. When building a c++ code for Android, you build it by means of NDK. I suggest you start with this [tutorial](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/android/Android_NDK.html), and first try to build a very simple C++ project with NDK, that compiles, and see that you're able to run on an Android device.
Things will get much clearer for you then.

After you mastered that, I suggest you start moving your code in small bits to that project, meanwhile replacing the OpenCV functions with stubs, and have that code compile and run (doing nothing) on Android.

After that, read about integrating OpenCV dependancy into an NDK project, this is not that hard (at least it wasn't in my case).

This [step-by-step](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/O4A_SDK.html) was pretty usefull for me.

As to the question whether you can "automagically" translate your (probably visual studio) project files into an Android NDK make files -- the answer is usually no. There are tools that'll claim to be able to do just that, but I was never successful with any of them.